# Permanently delete running / stopped / un-used containers using command?

Tags: docker

In case multiple containers are running then deleting one by one is time wasting
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`docker container stop $(docker container ls –aq) && docker system prune –af ––volumes`

The above command tells Docker to stop the containers listed in the parentheses.

Inside the parentheses, you tell `Docker` to generate a list of all the containers, and then the information is passed back to the container `stop` command and stops all the containers.

The `&&` attribute tells Docker to remove all stopped containers and volumes.

`–af` means this should apply to all containers `(a)` without a required confirmation `(f)`.

Answer (score -1):

Docker cli command :

`docker rm -f $(docker ps -qa)`

or

`docker system prune`

Create an Alias to do so every time

```
vi .bash_profile
alias dockererase='docker rm -f $(docker ps -qa)'
source ~/.bash_profile
```